# SQL Server: NOT EXISTS clause isn't stopping duplicates when the SQL executed parallelly

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012

I have three database tables like this:

```
book(book_id INT IDENTITY(1,1) PK, book_name VARCHAR(255), book_code INT UNIQUE)
series(series_id INT IDENTITY(1,1) PK, series_name VARCHAR(255), series_code INT UNIQUE)
bookseries(bookseries_id INT IDENTITY(1,1) PK, book_id INT FK, series_id INT FK) -- The combination (book_id + series_id) should be unique.
```

I have a functionality where the user can upload a spreadsheet with book_id and series_id populated (with around 50K records in the spreadsheet). 
When the spreadsheet is uploaded, I need to insert a record into bookseries table if the combination of book_id and series_id does not already exists in the bookseries table.

So, I am doing something like this (Pseudocode):

```
Dim sqlList As New List(Of String)
Dim sql As String = String.Empty
For each row in spreadsheetRows
    sql = String.Format("INSERT INTO bookseries(book_id, series_id) SELECT {0},{1} WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM bookseries WHERE book_id={0} AND series_id={1})", row.book_id, row.series_id)
    sqlList.Add(sql)

    If sqlList.Count MOD 500 = 0 Then insertListIntoDB(sqlList)
Next
If sqlList.Count > 0 Then insertListIntoDB(sqlList)
```

This is working correctly (inserting a record if it doesn't already exist) when one user uploads a spreadsheet. 
However, duplicate records being inserted into the `bookseries` table (duplicate `book_id + series_id`) when two users upload the spreadsheet and if the same records populated within the spreadsheet.

I couldn't understand why/how the duplicates are being inserted as I'm expecting the `WHERE NOT EXISTS` clause to stop the duplicate insertions.

Example: `INSERT INTO bookseries(book_id, series_id) SELECT 100, 1000 WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM bookseries WHERE book_id=100 AND series_id=1000)`

Could anyone advise why this isn't working as I'd expect or suggest if there is a workaround?

Thank you in advance.

PS: I am aware of the `parameterized SQL` usage, `SQL Injection`, `Dictionary`, and the drawbacks of executing the `raw SQL` directly on the server etc, so please do not question why I'm not using them in this instance. The above example is just to keep things simple and explain what I'm trying to achieve. My question is purely related to why the `NOT EXISTS` clause isn't stopping the duplicate insertions in my code.

Comment: Depends on when the queries are committed. In your case, I would suggest you insert all the ids in an array, push all the items at once in a temp table then do a query that copies from the temp table to the real table all the rows that aren't duplicate.

Comment: Where are the boundaries of your transaction?  Do you even have one?

Comment: Thank you for your comments, @the_lotus and @sstan. I haven't had a boundary, just executing the queries `(insert into ..;insert into...;insert into...;)` in one go.

Comment: @Sathish until the query is committed, the inserted values won't be available for other transactions to see.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is to put a unique constraint on book_id, series_id since they form the natural composite key of the link table. Then you just need to handle the unique constraint error (number 2601 or 2627) when you do an insert and continue processing.

it's not obvious to me why your current code isn't working as expected. Are two users trying to upload duplicate records at the same time? If so, my guess is that the transaction scope is wrong and you should commit after each insert instead of after all the records are processed.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps your WHERE clause SELECT SQL is returning Null?

How about:

```
... WHERE ((SELECT Count(*) FROM bookseries WHERE book_id=100 AND series_id=1000) = 0)
```

Comment: Is this a question, comment or an answer?

Comment: Yes it is a question, comment and a possible answer. I added the WHERE syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your requirements, and piggybacking off of Jamie, you may consider adding a unique index on the two columns mentioned with the addition of ignoring duplicates as a potential work around.  I don't have enough information about your application to know if this is a good suggestion, but it is an alternative.

In this example, the significant piece is **IGNORE_DUP_KEY = ON**.  This lets you try to insert duplicate rows, but SQL Server will silently ignore them.  This could have the added benefit of removing your `WHERE NOT EXISTS` check before inserting.

```
CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX [UCX_bookseries] ON dbo.bookseries
(
    book_id ASC,
    series_id ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = ON, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```